# Is it possible to query Hazelcast Cache? If yes, How to do it?

Tags: java, spring, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to implement caching using hazelcast.

Here's my code. My question is that, when findAllGames() is executed i am caching all the games in "gamesCache" and when findGameByTypes() is executed, I want it to query "gamesCache" instead of hitting the database and return the result.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "gamesCache", key = "#root.methodName")
public List<Game> findAllGames() {
    List<Game>  games = gamesDao.getAllGames(); // dao call
    //some database call
}

public List<Game> findGameByTypes(GameType gameType) {
    List<Game> games = gamesDao.getGamesByType(gameType); // dao call
    //some logic
}

public class Game implements Serializable {
    private long gameId;
    private String gameName;
    private GameType gameType;
}

public class GameType implements Serializable {
   private long gameId;
   private String gameGenre;
   private Boolean status;
}
```

findAllGames() is always hit first than findGamesByTypes().

Now the cached map is generated with "findAllGames" as key and List of games as value. Now Is there any way to query the map using the GameType attributes as criteria.

Is there any way to implement this? I am open to other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @wildnez, you can use PRedicate and/or SQLQuery. Also, since you're using Spring, you can also benefit from Spring-Data-Hazelcast project which automatically generates queries for you from method name: https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast

But you need to change your way of caching. Instead of having only one entry in the cache, with key `findAllGames` and storing all games in a collection, you should store all entries individually in the cache, `gameId` as key & `Game` as value. This way you can query values using either of the methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can query Hazelcast Map/Cache using Predicate or SqlQuery. Check out detail documentation here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query

Comment: Yes, I have looked into this. I followed the employee example in Querying with criteria Api. However I have a doubt that  what will this return hazelcastInstance.getMap("findAllGames")? A map with "findAllGames" as key and List<Game> as value. If yes, how to structure the predicate to query the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the MapLoader provided by Hazelcast. https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/MapLoader.html

You would have to implement a loadAll which would be a call to your findAllGames() which would save the key as gameType against the object.

Any call to load should be a call findGameByTypes which would be invoked if it wasnt able to find the data in the cache.

Have a look at this blog to ensure you understand the pitfalls involved.
https://dzone.com/articles/hazelcasts-maploader-pitfalls

Comment: I have added more details to the question. It may give a fair idea of what I want to achieve. Could you elaborate your answer a bit more or provide an example.?

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying. Hazelcast does support criteria based queries. https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query . You would need to setup a predicate. I havent tried on a composite object but for simple objects it should work. Please give it a try and let us know

Comment: I have gone through that link. Here the name of my cache is "gamesCache" and the key i used is "findAllGames". In the example provided in the link in the "Querying with Criteria Api" section, they do this                    IMap<String, Employee> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("employee"); I am having difficulty in understanding what this returns. I mean what are the key and values of this map.?

Comment: you are creating a cache with the key as the method name. instead of this you could go ahead with a query to the repository using the Game Data retrieved save them into a Hazelcast map with gameId as key and the Game as object. Hazelcast stores its data in a map so you need to align your data to the same pattern