# Hazelcast Sql queries in java

Tags: java, hazelcast

How to use select, where and from in hazelcast sql queries?

In there any way to query hazelcast grid like  how we do it with normal databases?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Refer here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369433/is-it-possible-to-query-hazelcast-cache-if-yes-how-to-do-it . Be more specific while asking the question.

Answer (score -1):

[Java Code Examples for com.hazelcast.query.SqlPredicate](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.hazelcast.query.SqlPredicate)